# iOS 8 Crash on relaunch when UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = Yes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8

When setting `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = Yes` in the info.list file ("Application does not run in background") the app will terminate when it is suspended.

On iOS7, when suspending an app with that setting by tapping on the home button, then after 1 second tapping the app icon again to relaunch it, it will shortly show the Default screen and launch OK.

On iOS8 however, tapping the icon to re-launch after a suspend will lead to a black screen and crash of the app, even before reaching `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Can anyone confirm this, and/or have a solution?

A work-around is to set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = No` but that is not the app behaviour that I desire.

Comment: Do you get any crashlogs from the system when this occurs?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue. We fixed it by putting an `exit(0)` in the appDelegate in either:

```
applicationWillResignActive
```

or

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

We see no crash log on the device when the app crashes.